# Undefined symbol in Clang-compiled Python extension using OpenMP

Tags: clang, openmp, python-c-api, undefined-symbol

I am facing a weird problem when compiling a Python extension featuring OpenMP with Clang.

## Minimal Example

I managed to boil down my actual problem to the following code:
The Python extension could not be much simpler, while still featuring OpenMP.
Apart from the function `bar`, this is mostly standard boilerplate:

```
# include <Python.h>

static PyObject * bar(PyObject *self)
{
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {float x=42.0; x+=1;}
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef foo_methods[] = {
    {"bar", (PyCFunction) bar, METH_NOARGS, NULL},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "foo", NULL, -1,
    foo_methods, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_foo(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
}
```

With the above being `foo.c`, I compile and load this with:

```sh
clang -fPIC -fopenmp -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c foo.c -o foo.o
clang -shared foo.o -o foo.so -lgomp
python3 -c "import foo"
```

The last line, i.e., the import of the module throws the following error:

> ImportError: /home/wrzlprmft/…/foo.so: undefined symbol: __kmpc_for_static_fini

## What I found out so far

- This does not happen when replacing Clang with GCC.
- This does not happen with regular shared libraries (not involving Python).
- Using Setuptools to compile the extension does not help.
  (In fact, my compile commands are a reduction of what Setuptools does to find out whether it uses any non-essential compiler extensions that cause this.)
- All of this happens on Ubuntu 19.10 with Python 3.7, Clang 9.0.0-2, and GCC 9.2.1.
- I can also replicate the problem on current Arch Linux with Python 3.8 and Clang 9.0.1.
- This worked until a year ago, probably longer.
- Using Python 3.6 does not help.
- Using Clang 3.8, 4.0, 6.0, 7, or 8 does not help.
- [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35517), somebody reports a similar problem when trying to compile TensorFlow.
  This is yet unsolved.

## Question

What is going wrong here and how can I fix this?
Right now I do not even have an idea whether this is an error by me, in Clang, OpenMP, or Python.

Comment: is that helping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715979/parallel-program-giving-error-undefined-reference-to-kmpc-ok-to-fork ?

Comment: @MrCas: Kind of. Adding `-fopenmp` to the second compilation step solves the problem for the minimal example, but only when using Clang as a compiler there. Unfortunately it turns out that Setuptools doesn’t respect my compiler choice here, but that’s a different problem. (Feel free to expand your comment to an answer.)

Comment: Using -lgomp definitely won't provide the runtime functions clang requires. (Though the converse, using CLANG's libomp.so instead of libgomp.so should for GCC compiled code!)

Comment: there is no need to add `-lgomp` if `-fopenmp` is added - the frontend (gcc or clang) will pick up the right dependency automatically.